# MariaDB, generate an id with both char and int

Tags: sql, mariadb

Hi i got a table with a field called `seriale` as a varchar(24).

Im trying to run this BEFORE INSERT trigger which need to generate an id, this are a few examples of ids i need to generate 'NOSN986423' 'NOSN468392', the NOSN is in every id i need to make, but the interger needs to be randomly generated and unique.

The current state of this is
`SET NEW.seriale = 'NOSN'||CAST(FLOOR(RAND(UUID_SHORT()) % 100000) AS CHAR);`

which is giving me this error (Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'NOSN')

Comment: does your structure apply to the conditions? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid_short/

Comment: @Martin seriale is declared as a vachar(24), UUID_SHORT should generate  an id that should be 17 characthers + 4 charachthers of the 'NOSN', so if thats what ur were asking i should be fine with the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default || is used as OR operator, but not as string concatenation operator:

```
SELECT 1 || 0;
+--------+
| 1 || 0 |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

If you want to use || for concatenation, you have to change sql mode:

```
set sql_mode="PIPES_AS_CONCAT";

select "foo" || "bar";
+----------------+
| "foo" || "bar" |
+----------------+
| foobar         |
+----------------+
```

However your number generation doesn't make sense, since it will always return 0.

Comment: Thanks for your response, then how would you generate the number and concattenate it with the 'NOSN' string?

Comment: RAND() produces a value between 0 and 1. A number < 1 modulus (=%) 100000 will always be 0. Maybe better to multiply it with 100000 ?

Comment: thanks again, and what should i use to concatenate it with the 'NOSN' string, ive tried to use '+' but its not working.

Comment: How about using a search engine or to read the MariaDB documentation instead of adding asking 3rd question?

Comment: Sorry i was not trying to be rude, i just didint have much time to put in it cause im very busy at work. Ive managed to make it work with ```SET NEW.seriale = CONCAT('NOSN-', CAST(UUID_SHORT() AS CHAR));```